# how to get an attribute value from fxml file?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Is there a loder method to get attribute value of fxml file ?

I mean from loader is there a way to use somthing like loader.meth1().meth2()...

for example I would like to get the fx:controller value

**sof.fxml** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="964.0" prefWidth="1209.0" stylesheets="@../../extension/extension.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="vue.vuetestCtrl" />
```

java file :

```
package repTest;

import java.net.URL;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import repTest.jfreeChart.chartTestMain;

public class GetFxmlInfo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        
        URL location = chartTestMain.class.getResource("/repTest/sof.fxml");    
        System.out.println("loc"+location);
        final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(location);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Via an `FXMLLoader`? No, I don't think you can do what you want. But you could use the [`java.xml` module](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.xml/module-summary.html) to parse the FXML file (which is really just an XML file), get the root element, and look for the `fx:controller` attribute.

Comment: “I would like to get the fx:controller” -> call [`loader.getController()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getController())

Answer (score 0):

You can get the controller class as a String  , but you need to load  your loader object first .

```
package repTest;

import java.net.URL;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import repTest.jfreeChart.chartTestMain;

public class GetFxmlInfo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    
   URL location = chartTestMain.class.getResource("/repTest/sof.fxml");    
   System.out.println("loc"+location);
   final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(location);
   loader.load();
   String string = loader.getController().getClass().toString();
    
   System.out.println(string);
    
}

}
```

Comment: Sorry i should precise that what I want is the fx:controller value before instanciation while getController() not simply catch the property.

Comment: ok , I think what @Slaw wrote is  better